# Is their a way to serve static files from the server to display in asp.net core 5 web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

So instead of using a CDN - i wanted to create a web app, place it onto a server, and then request files from the app, when needed to use on other web apps (Is this possible).

Example - App on server (Store a video and a couple of images) - Web App 2, request the video from the server and use it in Web App 2? Would this work the same as a cdn, and if so, is their also an easy option to set a cache time?

I know nothing is normally simple in coding, but i would just like to call the web app from web app 2, with the image path - i.e https://Someapp.co.uk/video/blah.mov

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: The distinction between a server making failes available to different application and a CDN in the context of this question is minimal. All a CDN is (again in the context of this question) is a different server hosting static files.

Comment: ok, so if i create a . net core web app, and place it on the server, i should just be able to call it from any app, with the url? Its kind of the same thing. is their a way to set a cache lifespan?

Comment: Depending on the server and your specific requirements, you probably won't need to get ASP.NET involved at all. For example, in IIS, you can just create a site, application, or virtual directory pointing to a folder on your server's disk, and have it serve up the static files for you directly.